# Positioning absolute elements that are relative to outside elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created this step through wizard using JavaScript supplemented by jQuery and I like the effect of having the previous step slide to the left as the new step slides in from the right. In order to do this I needed to setup the .review-item class so that it has a position of absolute. However, when I string the screen horizontally the previous and next buttons go over the content of that step. I have read other topics and found that you can position elements absolute and have their direct parents in a relative position, which would allow the absolute elements to be relative in it's parent element. This doesn't seem to be working. As you will see in the below video, the previous, and next buttons become in the same view as the content when the screen shrinks to a smaller size.

How can I make this absolute positioning of the step through content happen, but at the same time have it be relative to other outside elements such as the previous and next buttons?

https://youtu.be/gWUjwItWSN4

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
        .wizardContainer{
          position:relative;
          display:block;
          /* box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #888888; */
          float: none;
          margin: 0 auto;
          max-width:1021px;
          min-height:600px;



        }
        .review-item{
          display:none;
          position:absolute;
        }
      </style>

      <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
      <!-- <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

   </head>
   <body style="" class="">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12" style="padding: 100px;">
    <div class="wizardContainer">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align:center;min-height:150px;">
          <p class="review-item">
            Bacon ipsum dolor amet sirloin ribeye turkey shank short loin t-bone doner brisket spare ribs tenderloin cow short ribs chuck meatloaf chicken. Tail filet mignon meatloaf, ribeye turducken turkey leberkas spare ribs shankle. Prosciutto andouille pork belly short loin, hamburger pork kevin ball tip capicola swine brisket chuck meatloaf. Bresaola kielbasa pastrami frankfurter shank picanha sausage meatloaf tri-tip porchetta ball tip leberkas andouille bacon.

            Frankfurter pastrami pork, chicken venison spare ribs swine. Hamburger fatback ribeye, burgdoggen picanha frankfurter tongue turducken ground round capicola corned beef pork ham leberkas. Short loin frankfurter shoulder capicola kielbasa ball tip cow cupim filet mignon jerky bresaola. Meatball frankfurter filet mignon, prosciutto shankle strip steak turkey shoulder ham hock. Porchetta beef ribs alcatra, chuck shoulder pastrami biltong turducken tenderloin. Pork belly brisket burgdoggen frankfurter prosciutto jowl. Alcatra burgdoggen corned beef fatback pancetta buffalo."
          </p>
          <p class="review-item">
            "Brisket meatball ground round ribeye, picanha doner boudin ball tip pastrami bacon chicken. Pork chop leberkas bacon, biltong frankfurter cow picanha pork belly hamburger turkey drumstick corned beef meatloaf. Beef ribs alcatra burgdoggen, jerky beef strip steak shankle."
            <!-- <input id="textValue" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2"> -->
          </p>

          <p class="review-item">
              "Buffalo ham hock meatball t-bone jowl filet mignon pork belly. Leberkas venison chicken corned beef alcatra strip steak hamburger flank. Shank tri-tip short loin porchetta alcatra brisket boudin."
            </p>
          <p class="review-item">
              "Meatloaf pork loin chuck, drumstick beef ribs tongue pork belly. Biltong filet mignon frankfurter, drumstick boudin buffalo jerky porchetta burgdoggen tail meatball pork chop cow kielbasa. Corned beef pork loin ribeye pastrami swine beef prosciutto."
            </p>
        </div>


    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6" style="text-align:left;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-previous">Previous</button></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6" style="text-align:right;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-next">Next</button></div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$( document ).ready(function() {   
  var stepsLength = document.getElementsByClassName("review-item").length -1;
  var i=0
  console.log(stepsLength);
  var reviewItem = $('.review-item');
  $( reviewItem[0] ).css('display','block');

  $(".btn-next").click(function(){
    console.log(i);
    console.log($("#textValue").val());
    if(i>=0 && i<stepsLength){
      $( reviewItem[i] ).removeClass( "animated bounceInRight" );
      $( reviewItem[i] ).removeClass( "animated bounceOutRight" );
      $( reviewItem[i] ).addClass( "animated bounceOutLeft" );
      i++;
      $( reviewItem[i] ).css('display','block');
      $( reviewItem[i] ).removeClass( "animated bounceOutRight" );
      $( reviewItem[i] ).addClass( "animated bounceInRight" );
    }else{
      alert("The End");
    }


  })
  $(".btn-previous").click(function(){
    console.log(i);
    if(i>0){
      $( reviewItem[i] ).removeClass( "animated bounceInRight" );    
      $( reviewItem[i] ).addClass( "animated bounceOutRight" );
      i--;
      $( reviewItem[i] ).css('display','block');
      $( reviewItem[i] ).removeClass( "animated bounceOutLeft" );
      $( reviewItem[i] ).addClass( "animated bounceInLeft" );
    }else{
      alert("You cannot go any further back");
    }

  })

});
// ]]></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <style>
      .wizardContainer {
        /*position:relative;*/
        display: block;
        /* box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #888888; */
        float: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 1021px;
        min-height: 600px;
      }

      .review-item {
        display: none;
      }

      .review-item.active {
        display: block !important;
      }

    </style>

    <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
    <!-- <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body style="" class="">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="padding: 100px;">
        <div class="wizardContainer">
          <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align:center;min-height:150px;">
            <p class="review-item active">
              Bacon ipsum dolor amet sirloin ribeye turkey shank short loin t-bone doner brisket spare ribs tenderloin cow short ribs chuck meatloaf chicken. Tail filet mignon meatloaf, ribeye turducken turkey leberkas spare ribs shankle. Prosciutto andouille pork
              belly short loin, hamburger pork kevin ball tip capicola swine brisket chuck meatloaf. Bresaola kielbasa pastrami frankfurter shank picanha sausage meatloaf tri-tip porchetta ball tip leberkas andouille bacon. Frankfurter pastrami pork,
              chicken venison spare ribs swine. Hamburger fatback ribeye, burgdoggen picanha frankfurter tongue turducken ground round capicola corned beef pork ham leberkas. Short loin frankfurter shoulder capicola kielbasa ball tip cow cupim filet mignon
              jerky bresaola. Meatball frankfurter filet mignon, prosciutto shankle strip steak turkey shoulder ham hock. Porchetta beef ribs alcatra, chuck shoulder pastrami biltong turducken tenderloin. Pork belly brisket burgdoggen frankfurter prosciutto
              jowl. Alcatra burgdoggen corned beef fatback pancetta buffalo."
            </p>
            <p class="review-item">
              "Brisket meatball ground round ribeye, picanha doner boudin ball tip pastrami bacon chicken. Pork chop leberkas bacon, biltong frankfurter cow picanha pork belly hamburger turkey drumstick corned beef meatloaf. Beef ribs alcatra burgdoggen, jerky beef
              strip steak shankle."
              <!-- <input id="textValue" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2"> -->
            </p>

            <p class="review-item">
              "Buffalo ham hock meatball t-bone jowl filet mignon pork belly. Leberkas venison chicken corned beef alcatra strip steak hamburger flank. Shank tri-tip short loin porchetta alcatra brisket boudin."
            </p>
            <p class="review-item">
              "Meatloaf pork loin chuck, drumstick beef ribs tongue pork belly. Biltong filet mignon frankfurter, drumstick boudin buffalo jerky porchetta burgdoggen tail meatball pork chop cow kielbasa. Corned beef pork loin ribeye pastrami swine beef prosciutto."
            </p>
          </div>


        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6" style="text-align:left;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-previous">Previous</button></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6" style="text-align:right;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-next">Next</button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // <![CDATA[
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var stepsLength = document.getElementsByClassName("review-item").length - 1;
        var i = 0;
       
        var reviewItem = $('.review-item');

        $(".btn-next").click(function() {
         
          if (i >= 0 && i < stepsLength) {
            reviewItem.removeClass('active');
            reviewItem.eq(i).addClass("active");
            i++;
          } else {
            alert("The End");
          }


        })
        $(".btn-previous").click(function() {
         
          if (i > 0) {
            reviewItem.removeClass('active');
            reviewItem.eq(i).addClass("active");
            i--;
          } else {
            alert("You cannot go any further back");
          }

        })

      });
      // ]]>

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Is this what you desire? I deleted animations just to focus on the result.

Comment: Yes, but now that it is not absolute, and if you add animations, you will notice that the content moves in a downward direction when you click next and in an upwards direction when you hit previous.